# Manipulating pandas groups

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find ways of analysing log data from a git repo. I've dumped the data to a file that looks like this:

```
"hash","email","date","subject"
"65319af6e","jbrockmendel@gmail.com","2020-11-28","REF-IntervalIndex._assert_can_do_setop-38112"
"0bf58d8a9","simonjayhawkins@gmail.com","2020-11-28","DOC-add-contibutors-to-1.2.0-release-notes-38132"
"d16df293c","45562402+rhshadrach@users.noreply.github.com","2020-11-28","TYP-Add-cast-to-ABC-Index-like-types-38043"
"2d661a899","jbrockmendel@gmail.com","2020-11-28","CLN-simplify-mask_missing-38127"
"ba2ae2f73","jbrockmendel@gmail.com","2020-11-28","CLN-remove-unreachable-in-core.dtypes-38128"
```

I am able to get rows that have a count more than:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
dataframe = pd.read_csv("git-log-2020.csv")

dataframe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['date'])
grouped_dataframe = dataframe.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'), "email"])[["subject"]].count()

# Select all the users that have contributed more than 20 times.
print(grouped_dataframe[grouped_dataframe['subject'] > 20])
```

But I would like to be able to find the following:

- What is the top three users per month?
- What are the total commits for each month?
- what is the average number of commits per user / per month? What is the monthly average activity of the users?

My code and data can be found here: https://github.com/mooperd/git-analysis-pandas

Ta, Andrew

Answer (score 0):

All answers using your sample data that I call df

Top three :

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).apply(lambda d: d['email'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(3))
```

produces

```
date        email                                       
2020-11-30  jbrockmendel@gmail.com                          3
            simonjayhawkins@gmail.com                       1
            45562402+rhshadrach@users.noreply.github.com    1
Name: email, dtype: int64
```

total commits per month

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'))['subject'].count()
```

output:

```
date
2020-11-30    5
Freq: M, Name: subject, dtype: int64
```

as for average number of commits per user/per month not entirely clear what you want? For each user, the ratio of the number of commits for that user by the number of months in your dataset? or the number of months they made actual commits?. Would be useful to get sample output here

But I think the following transformation is useful, it produces a table of # of commits by email and month so you can take averages every which way

```
df2 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')])['email'].value_counts().unstack(level=0)
df2
```

On your real data it produces a table that is too large to reproduce here but it starts with

```
date                                    2020-01-31  2020-02-29  2020-03-31  2020-04-30  2020-05-31  2020-06-30  2020-07-31  2020-08-31  2020-09-30  2020-10-31  2020-11-30
email                                           
10430241+xh2@users.noreply.github.com   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN
12420863+danchev@users.noreply.github.com   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN
12769364+tnwei@users.noreply.github.com NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
12874561+jeet-parekh@users.noreply.github.com   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN
```

as you can see it has a lot of NaNs that correspon to users not making any commits that month, which is useful when eg calculating averages over months with commits.For example

```
df2.mean(axis=1).sort_values(ascending = False)
```

produces average monthly commits for a user (sorted), and

```
df2.mean(axis=0).sort_values(ascending = False)
```

produces average monthly commits per month (sorted)

Comment: Hi, I used your example but didn't get the expected output.
```dataframe.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'))['email'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(3)```
result:<br/>
 date        email         <br/>        
 2020-10-31  jbrockmendel@gmail.com    170<br/>
 2020-03-31  jbrockmendel@gmail.com    167<br/>
 2020-01-31  jbrockmendel@gmail.com    159<br/>
 Name: email, dtype: int64<br/>

Comment: @AndrewHolway you are using your real data I assume, I was using what you typed up in your question. Are those not the top 3 contributors? The number is the the number of commits if it is not clear

Comment: I am looking for the top three contributors per month.

Comment: https://github.com/mooperd/git-analysis-pandas/blob/master/git-log-pitar.py

Comment: @AndrewHolway ah I see, sorry about that. Fixed the first answer, should work now hopefully

Comment: @AndrewHolway also added some suggestions on the last question